# SQL Query to build a delimited string for a column for each distinct id in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables that have 2 columns each.

'Column 1' is the 'One' 
'Column 2' is the 'Many'

Column 1 has several different ID's that i need to group somehow and build a delimited string of all the 'Columns 2' values.

I need to do this for every distinct 'Column 1' value.... is this possible?

So for example i have this table..

```
DECLARE @tblDeadsData TABLE (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ContainerID] INT NULL,
    [DeadsID] INT NULL
    )
```

It is already populated with data, i need to build a delimited string of ALL the [DeadsID] for each [ContainerID], and then these delimited string need to be placed into this table (the DeadsDataTable Data goes into the tblLastMerge.DeadsIDList in this case)..

```
CREATE TABLE tblLastMerge(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FeedLotID] INT NULL,
    [ContainerID] INT NULL,
    [ContainerName] VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    [IsMergeTargetContainer] BIT NULL,
    [PurchaseIDList] VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    [DeadsIDList] VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    [RailersIDList] VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    [FeedBillIDList] VARCHAR(1000) NULL
    )
```

***************************EDIT*********************************
in regards to the duplicate post.........Concatenation is not delimited!!!!!! no wonder when i did a search for my problem i did not see this post..... i do think you should link these 2 post though as i found an answer much more simplified compared to the (supposedly) original post

Comment: This question is not readable.  Please clean up the formatting.

Comment: Can you please add some table values and expected output?

Comment: Do not post your code snapshots instead post the code..!

Comment: Added `sql-server` and `t-sql` tags based on the code given

Comment: values and output ...... i want a delimited list of column [DeadsID] separated  (grouped by if you will) by [ContainerID]. just that much would be progress for now :)

Comment: i can currently get the delimited string of ALL of [DeadsID] using this code select cast([DeadsID] as varchar) + ',' from @tbldeadsdata  for xml path('') but i need multiple strings returned if there is more than 1 [ContainerID]...1 for each container

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...... i found an answer

--table to hold the old deads data
    DECLARE @tblDeadsData TABLE (
        [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ContainerID] VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        [DeadsID] VARCHAR(10) NULL
        )

```
insert into @tbldeadsdata
    values('1','2'),('1','3'),('1','4'),('2','2'),('2','3'),('2','4')


SELECT ContainerID, DeadsID = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + DeadsID 
  FROM @tblDeadsData AS p2
   WHERE p2.ContainerID = p.ContainerID 
   ORDER BY DeadsID
   FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
FROM @tblDeadsData AS p
GROUP BY ContainerID
ORDER BY ContainerID
```